# How do I do logical AND in regexp to match both patterns simultaneously?

Tags: c#, regex

The problem is to match all punctuation marks in a given text. There is the descriptor **\W** that matches any non-word character (including white-space character), and there's **\S** that matches any non-white-space character. How do I write a regular expression that matches any non-word non-white-space character?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just negate the `[\w\s]` with `^`: `[^\w\s]`. See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/eD8bJ6/1). As you can see there, this will "match a single character not present in the list".

Basically, you need to learn about logic operations. NOR ("not or") operations can form any other logical operations. See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NOR_logic) wiki article for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Use a negated char class.

```
[^\w\s]
```

This won't match a word character and at the space time, that character must not be a space character.

Comment: @Glinka i'm the one who posted first then why you accept the other answer? You may check it clicking the oldest tab.

Comment: ok, consider if another one come with another answer that is exactly the same as mine and the other guy which has lot and lot more of explanations even he included a regex book on his answer. In that case which answer you did choose?

Comment: Actually, when I click onto the oldest tab, Asunez's question comes first. Might be a glitch, but you answered almost simultaneously. And I'm sorry, I didn't mean to upset you.